# Python calculating datetime - Is date today between a certain datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

I have users who get a special offer for 6 months on registration. I save the datetime of the registration and know that this datetime + 6 months is the special offer.

Now I need after 5 month to display a button which reminds them that the offer is running out in 1 month.

So I need to check whether datetime.now() is within range:

```
user1 = datetime(2017,4,30)
user2 = datetime(2017,5,25)
user3 = datetime(2017,1,11) 
user4 = datetime(2017,2,20)
user5 = datetime(2017,12,23)
user6 = datetime(2017,7,22) 

list_of_users = [user1,user2,user3,user4,user5,user6]

for user_date in list_of_users:
    if datetime.now() < user_date + relativedelta(months=6) and datetime.now() > user_date + relativedelta(months=5):
        print user_date, "yes"
```

I have created some examples and user5 should be within this range, but somehow it wont recognize it.

Comment: user5's date is *in the future* (over 5 months from today). Did you mean it to be a  date in 2016 instead?

Comment: I confused myself playing with the dates. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works just fine, albeit a bit verbose. `user5` does **not** qualify your criteria, the data is 5+ months in the future, not in the past. Their *special offer* period *has not yet started*, let alone be 1 month away from expiring. They should only see the warning between the 23rd of May and June of **2018**.

You can more concisely test by storing the cut-off dates first, and using chained comparisons:

```
now = datetime.now()
started_min, started_max = now - relativedelta(months=6), now - relativedelta(months=5)
for user_date in list_of_users:
    if started_min <= user_date <= started_max:
         print user_date, "yes"
```

So if a user started their offer between 5 and 6 months ago, they need to be reminded now, because they are in their last month.